# How can I add padding to a tkinter window, without tkinter centering the widget?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

How can I add padding to a tkinter window, without tkinter centering the widget?

```
self.canvas_l = Label(self.master, text="Heading", font="helvetica 12")
self.canvas_l.pack(anchor=tk.NW, ipadx=20)
```

Comment: You can add asymmetrical padding by passing a tuple to `padx` and `pady` like `padx=(0,20)`. See http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/pack.htm#M19

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have your full code, but you should try putting it in a 'frame'

you can probably center the frame, but you will be able to off-center the label inside.

this is a bit cheezy, but due to the nature of padding it will be hard.

Comment: also of you have trouble with Tkinter you can probably try PAGE.

Comment: Having full code is not necessary. You can make a simple one.

Comment: @BlackThunder what i usually do is i give the fixed code/code answer back in the answer post, but because i don't have the full code i can't make a copy-paste fix-works system

Comment: Why don't create one?

Comment: @Timo Herngreen thanks for your answer.  It worked!!